# Resize text to fit label size in libGDX

Tags: java, android, text, libgdx, label

I'm adding a Label object with some text to a stage. Before that I change the Label width,height, etc... The problem I have with it is that the text never changes to fit the Label. Is there a way to make some text fit the size of a Label?

Code:

```
 LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle(font,Color.BLACK);
 label = new Label("HI!",labelStyle);
 label.setPosition(0,0);
 label.setScale(100,100);
 stage.addActor(label);
```

Comment: are you using the Label inside a TableLayout?

Comment: Nope. i'm just creating a Label and then assigning a position and size. Then I add it to the stage.

Comment: Actually I have the same question...because I can't understand if the Label automatically manages the dimensions of the text or it semply serves as an object that takes care of the position of the text.
It's very confusing because I wished the Label was able to handle the drawing of the text changing it's width and height......
Reading the guide the doubt isn't solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it would be good to put some code, 
maybe this help you

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui

> "invalidate invalidateHierarchy"

new 
look this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/LabelScaleTest.java